# Logger throws IncompatibleClassChangeError at runtime when processing a custom log message class

Tags: java, log4j2

I have the implementation as follow in the library A

```
public class CustomLogMessage implements Message { //some implementation }
```

then, that library A is taken into B (via maven dependency) and has the follow implementation in B:

```
public class JohnDoe {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(JohnDoe .class);
    
   
    public static void message(some args) {
        LOGGER.info(new CustomLogMessage(args));
    }
    
}
```

Through the unit test, this work perfectly fine but when I deploy this app locally, the logger threw **IncompatibleClassChangeError** exception with the inner most stacktrace is **AbstractAppender** class from log4j.

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1290)
```

Before this implementation, the B used to work with log4j (1.2.17) and back the the **CustomLogMessage** class just need to implement the Serializable interface and then it can already be passed into the logger's argument.

But after B is upgraded to log4j2 (2.17.1), the **CustomLogMessage** class now need to implement the Message interface. (see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html)

I have no idea why this happened nor the actual meaning of the exception.
Can someone point out why I got this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was Lib C that has a reference to the old implementation of the **CustomLogMessage** class and this lib C was loaded first by the JVM and therefore when it reached this line `LOGGER.info(new CustomLogMessage(args));` during run-time, it threw the exception (binary incompatible).